# Salt in tank DEQ. When is salt gone?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> One tank contains 300 liters of water mixed with 50 g of salt. 3
> liters of clean water are pumped in every minute. The mixed solution
> is pumped out at 3 liters per minute. Determine a differential
> equation for the amount of salt after $x$ minutes. When is all the
> salt gone?

$$y=amount\ of\ salt\ by\ x\ minutes. \frac{salt\ gram}{water\ liter}\\y'=salt\ in - salt\ out\\salt\ in=0\\salt\ out=\frac{3y}{300}\\y'=-\frac{3y}{300}\Rightarrow y'+\frac{1}{100}\cdot y=0\Rightarrow y=e^{\frac{-x-c}{100}}$$

We know that $y(0)=\frac{50}{300}$, which gives $\frac{50}{300}=e^{\frac{-0-c}{100}}\Rightarrow c=100ln(6)$

$$\Rightarrow y=e^{\frac{-x-100ln(6)}{100}}$$

When is $y=0$? $$0=e^{\frac{-x-100ln(6)}{100}}\Rightarrow No\ solutions$$

What am I missing?

Comment: I would suspect a literal answer would be never.  In other words, you are continuously diluting the amount of salt in the tank.  The continuous model never reaches zero.  I guess in practice when the amount of salt remaining is modelled to be one molecule, it becomes a fair bet that at point after that the one NaCl molecule randomly gets washed out, but the model does not address that.

Comment: Ooh! My conclusion was that I must have miscalculated. Thank you for explaining how I should interpret it all. Have a nice day!

Comment: @hardmath I think you should post your comment as an answer so the question moves off the unanswered queue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm posting my edit, the answer, as the comment requested.

$$y=amount\ of\ salt\ by\ x\ minutes. \frac{salt\ gram}{water\ liter}\\y'=salt\ in - salt\ out\\salt\ in=0\\salt\ out=\frac{3y}{300}\\y'=-\frac{3y}{300}\Rightarrow y'+\frac{1}{100}\cdot y=0\Rightarrow y=e^{\frac{-x-c}{100}}$$

We know that $y(0)=\frac{50}{300}$, which gives $\frac{50}{300}=e^{\frac{-0-c}{100}}\Rightarrow c=100ln(6)$

$$\Rightarrow y=e^{\frac{-x-100ln(6)}{100}}$$

When is $y=0$? $$0=e^{\frac{-x-100ln(6)}{100}}\Rightarrow No\ solutions$$

Therefor the salt never truly disappear.